# Reading the dataframe syntax

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm pretty new to R.

I just imported a CSV file into my R environment. I see the name of the dataframe and the name of the columns, but there is information below and I don't know what to make of it.

It looks like it might be records of the data types that R guessed when it imported the data, but I'm not sure. Can you confirm what it's communicating? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide `str(this_is_fun)` and `dput(this_is_fun)` if possible?

Answer (score 2):

The functions in the `readr` package add an extra `spec` attribute to the data they read in. It won't affect anything in later code. I assume it is intended for debugging purposes in case your data is imported poorly, you can see what was used so you can try something different in a manual override.

It's mentioned a bit in the [`readr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/readr.html), especially the last two sections. You can access the `spec` attribute directly with either `attr(your_data, "spec")` or `spec(your_data)`.